# Restrict .Net Core API URL for specific URL path segment version

Tags: c#, rest, api, .net-core

I have started as a newbee on **.Net Core**, and trying to set versioning on the `controller` (*URL Path Segment Versoning*).

Following is my example `controller`

```
[ApiVersion( "1" )]
[Route( "api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]" )]
public class HelloWorldController : Controller {
    public string Get() => "Hello world!";
}
```

This is how I make version mandatory in `Startup` file

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{        
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddApiVersioning(v =>
    {
       v.ReportApiVersions = true;
    });
}
```

When I call API locally with following URL(s) the result is same i.e. success

```
<LocalHostUrlHere>/api/v1../HelloWorldController/
<LocalHostUrlHere>/api/v1.0./HelloWorldController/
<LocalHostUrlHere>/api/v1.0/HelloWorldController/
<LocalHostUrlHere>/api/v1/HelloWorldController/
```

Notice the above 4 calls has difference in API version. All these ApiCalls call the `HelloWorldController` `Get` method successfully.

Following URL(s) does not work (as expected)

```
<LocalHostUrlHere>/api/v1.../HelloWorldController/
<LocalHostUrlHere>/api/v1.11/HelloWorldController/
<LocalHostUrlHere>/api/v1.1/HelloWorldController/
<LocalHostUrlHere>/api/v2/HelloWorldController/
```

I am confused Why I get result on all URL's irrespective of version format !!.

Also is there any way to restrict API to only return result for url `<LocalHostUrlHere>/api/v1/HelloWorldController/`?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must use multiple `ApiVersion` attributes.

```
[ApiVersion("1.1")]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[ApiVersion("1.3")]
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
```

Comment: This will not help me, as I only want to put "1" in version. And dont want 1.0, 1.., 1.0. to work in version (as mentionedin question).